# Can't access php files in folder using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have troubles accessing my php files in a folder. When I click on the folder, it brings me to a page on chrome which says "Bad data passed, return to home (which is a hyperlink to the actual website)". Then when I click on the hyperlink, it runs on an online server of the main page instead of localhost. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the host to your local ip in the hosts file, in /etc/hosts add at the end of the file

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
127.0.0.1 www.yourdomain.com
```

where yourdomaoin.com is your domain. Put also the www subdomain if you use it

Comment: i can't find this file anywhere... could there be another name for it?

Comment: on windows: right click on notepad, select open as administrator, file->open->C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
on mac ???
on linux you have to run the command line, sudo nano /etc/hosts

Comment: I maybe misunderstood the question, if your problem is that the url brings you on a public domain instead of the local one then this it will help you, otherwise you can forget my answer

Comment: I tried this, but I don't have administrative access to the folder hence I can't do it. (And yes, thank you, you're on the right track, its exactly the issue I'm facing) Do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: If you have another pc with administrator access, you can do what I say before on this pc, then you have to use it as a router and connect your first pc on the created network:

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-your-computer-as-a-router

otherwise I think that there are no solution

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems with `.htaccess` (in root public_hrml folder). Try to rename it to `.htaccess_backup` and check again.
If that doesnt help, post here exactly what url you are being redirected to.

Comment: may I know the path to this folder? I don't know where it lies.